# Old image in Newsfeed still shown after being replaced in Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, newsfeed, picture

we have a problem with a Newsfeed web part. By replacing an image with a different image of the same name in the same library, the Newsfeed web part is still showing the old replaced image. We deleted the browser cache but it didn´t help. We also tried flushing the BLOB cache in the SharePoint Server, but it didn´t help either.

Did anyone had similar problems?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can trace the problem with below steps

- Go to your Newsfeed and inspect the image and check the path using browser developer tool (F12 Shortcut).
- Take your new image path.
- Compare these 2 image paths to make sure both are referring same paths.
- You can also check by placing paths in browser address and see which images it downloads.

Comment: I tested it on a test environment and somehow it worked. The image was immediately changed. Now we need to test it in the production environment. Will comment on that later.